# Whats the equivalent command for "docker.io -d -b br10 &" in centos7

Tags: centos, docker, centos-7

I am learning docker and need your help in below:
I have created a bridge network and want to add it to docker. The tutorial was performed on ubuntu so the tutor user "docker.io -d -b br10 &" to add the bridge network to docker.

I have centos7 system and its failing.

[root@server network-scripts]# docker -d -b br10 &  <== Failing here.
[1] 72919
[root@server network-scripts]# unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
See 'docker --help'.

Usage:  docker COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default "/root/.docker")
  -D, --debug              Enable debug mode
      --help               Print usage
  -H, --host list          Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -l, --log-level string   Set the logging level ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal") (default "info")
      --tls                Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
      --tlscacert string   Trust certs signed only by this CA (default "/root/.docker/ca.pem")
      --tlscert string     Path to TLS certificate file (default "/root/.docker/cert.pem")
      --tlskey string      Path to TLS key file (default "/root/.docker/key.pem")
      --tlsverify          Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version            Print version information and quit

Can anyone please help me?

Thank You!